# C# Use class properties as array

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a View Mode class.

```
public class VM_MyClass
{
    [Display(Name = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Date Of Birth")]
    public string DOB { get; set; }
}
```

I want to use its attributes like this:

```
VM_MyClass model = new VM_MyClass();
model[0] = "Alpha" // Name
model[1] = "11/11/14" // DOB
```

Is there any possibility?

Comment: [Indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) (although using 0 based indexes for named properties sounds like not the best idea)

Comment: No, but why do you want this? What you're trying to achieve?

Comment: @Andre, of course it's possible...

Comment: There is indeed a way using reflection that can do something very similar to this (you have to find the PropertyInfos and the use accessors) - but as @Andre said: why?

Comment: Mohsin, why exactly you want to do this? It's a bad idea however you look at it, probably from every possible angle of looking at it..

Comment: It is possible, but it's almost certain that there's a much better way of doing whatever it is you're trying to accomplish

Comment: I have a view model.. I am crawling data from a html file. So I am getting td's array which is giving me 1,24 values. Each value belongs to a specific property of my view model. I can do it by applying 24 if/else on the bases of counter but it seems not good. So I was wondering if there is a proper solution for this kind of problems.

Comment: You would need to use reflection, but be very careful with that. Make sure you don't use it too often and be aware of the performance considerations in areas where you do (profiling, etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an indexer and the reflection API like in the following example
(As other have said you must be very careful)

```
public class VM_MyClass
{
    private static Type ThisType = typeof(VM_MyClass);
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public DateTime DOB { get; set; }

    public object this[string propertyName]
    {
        get
        {
            return GetValueUsingReflection(propertyName);
        }
        set
        {

            SetValueUsingReflection(propertyName, value);
        }
    }

    private void SetValueUsingReflection(string propertyName, object value)
    {
        PropertyInfo pinfo = ThisType.GetProperty(propertyName);
        pinfo.SetValue(this, value, null);
    }
    private object GetValueUsingReflection(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyInfo pinfo = ThisType.GetProperty(propertyName);
        return pinfo.GetValue(this,null);
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
namespace Example
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        VM_MyClass model = new VM_MyClass();

        model["Name"] = "My name";
        model["DOB"] = DateTime.Today;

        Console.WriteLine(model.Name);
        Console.WriteLine(model.DOB);
        //OR
        Console.WriteLine(model["Name"]);
        Console.WriteLine(model["DOB"]);

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Georg Vovos, Thanks man for your answer, I also have solved it by this approach. As per my above comment I need to assign values of array to model attributes. So I found this way.

*I am using your approach, which is more appropriate :) thanks for help.*

```
    VM_MyClass model = new VM_MyClass();

    var ClassProperties = model.GetType().GetProperties();

    int counter = 0;
    foreach (var item in col)
    {
        Type type = model.GetType();

        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo propertyInfo = type.GetProperty(ClassProperties[counter].Name);

        propertyInfo.SetValue(model, item.InnerText);

        counter++;
    }
```